# Maintain reordered divs on refresh with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page that has divs for delivery points (each with a child arrival button) on a route, and I wrote a script that appends the delivery point div to an empty div at the bottom of the page when the arrival button is clicked. I would like to preserve the moved divs at the bottom of the page if the page is refreshed, so that my driver on this delivery route doesn't get confused about which delivery point on the route to go to next.

This is the simple click function script that I need to add an ajax call to. As an aside, both the buttons with the class `.arrived` and their parent divs are dynamically named in the ruby loop that's printing them both out on my view.

```
$(".arrived").click( function() {
  $("#item_" + $(this).attr("id")).appendTo("#delivered_collector");
});
```

I found another script elsewhere in the application that I THINK I can borrow logic from for this task, but I'm having some trouble making sense of it and how to translate it into my click function. This example preserves the state of checkboxes even if the page refreshes.

```
$('input.delivery_label_check').on('click', function(e)
{
  var $id=$(this).context.id.split("_")[2];
  var $checked=$(this).prop('checked');
  $.ajax({type: "POST",
      url: "/ops/mark_label/"+$id+"?checked="+$checked,
      success: function(data) {
      }});
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

If anyone can help me make enough sense of the second script to implement parts of it in the first, I'll be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// select an input with the delivery_label_check class
// whenever one of those appears on the page, add a click function to it
// it doesn't matter when one appears (that's what "on" does)
$('input.delivery_label_check').on('click', function(e)
{

// the click target has an id like "#name_thing_5" so split("_")
// makes ['name','thing','5'], then it gets the last item (aka '5')
  var $id=$(this).context.id.split("_")[2];

// is the box checked or not?
  var $checked=$(this).prop('checked');

// here is your ajax call
$.ajax({type: "POST",
  url: "/ops/mark_label/"+$id+"?checked="+$checked,
  success: function(data) {
  }});
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Does that help?